# Wordpress Pagination - loop posts

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way that I can change my pagination code to find the next or previous post even if there isn't a next post? So if I was on my first post it says "prev" and i want it to say next too and to find the last one posted. So it loops the posts. Not sure if this is possible

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'previous', TRUE); ?></li>
        <li><?php next_post_link('%link', 'next', TRUE); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, through `filters`.

```
/**
 * Functon creates default content for pagination function previous_post_link() and     next_post_link()
 * @param $original string HTML content returned by previous_post_link/next_post_link to be     modified
 * @return string
 */
function default_prev_next_link($original) {

    //if prev/next link does not exists, $original is empty string
    if(!$original)
        return "<a href='#'>new content</a>";

    //you need to return original value, in case it is set
    return $original;
}

//hook our function to filters
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'default_prev_next_link');
add_filter('next_post_link', 'default_prev_next_link');
```

Eventually, you can create two separate functions, which you hook into *_post link separately

Comment: Do I need to add this to my functions?

Comment: I added it but it doesnt seem to link to the next post. http://idobookcovers.com/book-cover-design/the-backpacking-preparation-guidebook/#

Comment: It works for me in a default theme `twentythirteen`. And yes, in functions. I am looking at your site, and found this, http://idobookcovers.com/book-cover-design/spotlight-series/, in the source sode, you are having an error, `c2c_next_or_loop_post_link` is undefined, what pagination functions are you using?